# scrapy: does it make sense to disable filtering on a formrequest?

Tags: python, scrapy

So I've been wondering regarding a spider, if maybe some of my requests might be getting filtered because they are to the url endpoint but with different body arguments (form data). Does the `dont_filter=True` make sense with FormRequest object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request has the dont_filter attribute set, the offsite middleware will allow the request even if its domain is not listed in allowed domains.